# How to route to another path with Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to redirect a URL-path in my Azure Web App service to another URL-path using Azure Application Gateway. How to avoid redirection to include the original path?

[image]
I have an ASP.NET framework 4.7 Web App service in Azure with two APIs:

```
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/values/{int}        -> respons 200
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/forbidden           -> respons 403
```

Then I have an App Gateway

```
http://myapp.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
```

With path-based route

```
http://myapp.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com -> https://myapp.azurewebsites.net (works ok)
```

And a permanent redirect to "external site"

```
/api/values/* -> http://myapp.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/forbidden
```

Now when I go to a path /api/values/1 it redirects me wrong to **/api/forbidden/api/values/1**

```
http://myapp.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/values/1 -> http://myapp.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/forbidden/api/values/1 !!!
```

Means redirection includes the origin path!
"Include path" is not checked and greyed-out in configuration.
[image]

I only want to restrict the access to some API-path from public Internet.

Comment: maybe happens because of precedence?

Comment: Hm.. Maybe. The question is how to avoid it. I could solve the problem just to deploy another Web service that just responses "403 forbidden", then add it as a pool to the gateway. But that looks overkill for a such simple requirement.

Comment: change the order of rules?

Comment: There is only one path-based rule, that redirects from gateway to pool, and adds that URL-path exception for /api/values/*. It is not possible to add more rules, since there is only one listener.  And there can be only single listener on the same port (80).

Answer (score 0):

For the `include path` configuration, I think you could try to set redirection for the listener with [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-url-redirect-cli#add-redirection-configuration) or [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-url-redirect-powershell#add-redirection-configuration) with `-IncludePath` parameter.

From *Redirect to external site* in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-overview), it should have option to disable the include path.

> With this change, customers need to create a new redirect
>   configuration object, which specifies the target listener or external
>   site to which redirection is desired. **The configuration element also
>   supports options to enable appending the URI path and query string to
>   the redirected URL**. You can also choose the type of redirection.
>   Once created, this redirect configuration is attached to the source
>   listener via a new rule. When using a basic rule, the redirect
>   configuration is associated with a source listener and is a global
>   redirect. When a path-based rule is used, the redirect configuration
>   is defined on the URL path map. So it only applies to the specific
>   path area of a site.