# How to restrict access to some URL-path of Azure Web service from Internet?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a classic ASP.NET 4.7 Azure Web service with an Web API.
How to restrict access to some URL-path of Azure Web service from Internet while allow to access the whole web site, and allow access to the restricted path from a VNet?
[image]

I tried to solve the problem using Azure Application Gateway, but it does not work properly. Here is the question [How to route to another path with Azure Application Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60300686/how-to-route-to-another-path-with-azure-application-gateway)

Comment: Do you have a chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

From perspective of coding, you could use this similar way instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473687/restrict-access-to-a-specific-controller-by-ip-address-in-asp-net-mvc-beta) to authorized on specific URL based on IP address.

From perspective for Azure Application Gateway, you could try using [custom rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/custom-waf-rules-overview):

```
Allowing and blocking traffic is simple with custom rules. 
For example, you can block all traffic coming from a range of IP addresses. 
You can make another rule to allow traffic if the request comes from a specific browser.
```

You can leverage "RequestUri" variable in Match variable section. (Not professional on WAF, so didn't test this way)